# Removing duplicates in a Pandas dataframe for only a specified value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'Value': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
})
```

If I wanted to only remove duplicates on ID when ID is a specified value (let's say 1), how would I do that? In other words, the resulting dataframe would look like:

```
|ID|Value|
|--|-----|
|1 |A    |
|2 |B    |
|3 |A    |
|2 |C    |
|3 |A    |
```

AI assistants are having a surprisingly difficult time with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a boolean mask with `DataFrame.duplicated`:

```py
mask = df.ID.eq(1) & df.duplicated(subset=["ID"])
print(df[~mask])
```

Prints:

```
   ID Value
0   1     A
1   2     B
2   3     A
4   2     C
5   3     A
```

---

Steps:

```py
print(df.ID.eq(1))

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool


print(df.duplicated(subset=["ID"]))

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool


mask = df.ID.eq(1) & df.duplicated(subset=["ID"])
print(mask)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```